Error evaluating dynamic reference in Visualforce with custom object
I'm running into a strange error when trying to display a custom field from a custom object dynamically on a visualforce page.
I'm getting this error
Unknown property '$ObjectType.CFIM__Request__c.fields.﻿CFIM__Notes__c'
Error is in expression '{!$ObjectType.Request__c.fields[f.apiName].label}' in component <apex:repeat> in component cfim:emailtemplatenew
Error evaluating dynamic reference 'CFIM__﻿Notes__c'

I've confirmed that f.apiName ('CFIM__Notes__c') is giving the correct value, and I tried to output it manually
{!$ObjectType.Request__c.fields['CFIM__Notes__c'].label}

and this works perfectly fine.
There are other fields that are included in this repeat (this field is just the example of other fields)

Check permissions to at least read this field for the user.

Please [edit] your post to include the relevant portions of the Visualforce code.
